# How to get list of all emitted events in truffle console?

Tags: solidity, truffle, events, truffle-migration

I wrote a very simple smart contract which emits an event everytime I call one of its functions:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract MyContract {

    event Score(
        uint date,
        string player,
        string team
    );

    function goalScored(string memory _player, string memory _team) external {
        emit Score(block.timestamp, _player, _team);
    }
}
```

Then I deploy the contract using `truffle migrate`. Finally I interact with the contract within the `truffle console`.
To do so I therefore load the contract by using the following lines of code:

```
MyContract.deployed().then(function(i) { contract=i;})
contract.goalScored('messi','inter')
```

Basically everytime Messi scores against a team a I launch the function to emit an Score event.

Here is my question: how can I visualize the list of all events within the truffle console?

What I tried: I ran the *goalScored()* function 4 times with different inputs and then I tried to used the following command:

```
contract.allEvents()
```

But all I got was this:

```
EventEmitter {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
}
truffle(development)> Uncaught [Error: The current provider doesn't support subscriptions: HttpProvider] {
  domainEmitter: EventEmitter {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
    _eventsCount: 0,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  },
  domainThrown: false
}
```

Would you be able to suggest a smart and elegant way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from truffle develop you could try something like

```
let c = await MyContract.deployed()
await c.goalScored('a','b')
let events = await c.getPastEvents('Score',{ fromBlock:0, toBlock:'latest'})
events
```

furthermore, if you need ALL events, you could use

```
c.getPastEvents('allEvents',{ fromBlock:0, toBlock:'latest'})
```

full truffle develop input:

```
migrate 
let c = await Messi.deployed()
await c.goalScored('first','inter')
await c.getPastEvents('allEvents',{fromBlock:0})
```

example output:

```
[
{
logIndex: 0,
transactionIndex: 0,
transactionHash: '0x3b09d2d01dd03c5bea61e84cc43529b9676a0be8d895b780aee00a42a7c0971d',
blockHash: '0x05cfc5a9204adb909dd4870ceb39c2376fc894fe06a8d6491888041bc91e1810',
blockNumber: 5,
address: '0x8D595a50a2F4cA295784fC2FFde8De6EE3346ca6',
type: 'mined',
id: 'log_fda64066',
returnValues: Result {
  '0': '1633018291',
  '1': 'first',
  '2': 'inter',
  date: '1633018291',
  player: 'first',
  team: 'inter'
},
event: 'Score',
signature: '0xba74004ad4978cd3d2ecfe8c15e7c5f91bd7da14e199e9ae8638f20f378a7293',
raw: {
  data: '0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006155e1b3000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000566697273740000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005696e746572000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  topics: [Array]
},
args: Result {
  '0': [BN],
  '1': 'first',
  '2': 'inter',
  __length__: 3,
  date: [BN],
  player: 'first',
  team: 'inter'
}
}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I just run your code but I get an empty list for some reason.... do you know what the issue could be?

Comment: Hi, I tried inside truffle console; allow me some time and I'll update the answer with the whole list of commands (it's already the one above though..)

Comment: @FedericoGentile a note; I replicated your situation if you deploy with c.deployed() without the migration. I don't know why it behaves this way

Comment: Perfect Thank you very much!!! You got it!